# How do I use asyncio to offload task in a discord bot?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, youtube-api, python-asyncio

I'm creating a discord bot where one of the commands (I'll call it `long_method()`) creates a call to the Youtube API and downloads comments. This takes a while and I want my bot to continue responding to other commands (`short_method()`, for example) while the comments are downloading.

Using asyncio, the definitions of my methods look like this:

```
@commands.command()
async def long_method(self, ctx, params):
    await ctx.send("starting long method")
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(self.long_method_helper(ctx, params))

async def long_method_helper(self, ctx, params):
    # download youtube comments
    # ...
    await ctx.send("long method complete")


@commands.command()
async def short_method(self, ctx):
    await ctx.send("short method called")
```

However, when I send the following to the discord channel, without waiting for the long method to finish:

```
+long_method
+short_method
```

The bot outputs:

```
long method started
[ takes time to process long method ]
long method finished
short method called
```

Instead, I want it to output:

```
long method started
short method called
[ time to process long method or responses to other methods]
long method finished
```

Is there something I'm missing? Shouldn't the call to `create_task(self.long_method_helper(ctx, params))` make it run in the background? Thanks!

Edit: the contents of `long_method_helper`:

```
    async def search_yt_helper(self, query, confirmation_ctx):        
        # get video ids and titles from Comments package
        video_ids, video_titles, channels = await Comments.youtube_search_keyword(self.api_key, query, max_results=5)
        n = 0
        new_comments = pd.DataFrame()
        logging.info(f"got {len(video_ids)} results")
        # for each video, get comments from id and add them to new_comments dataframe
        for v_id in video_ids:
            c = await Comments.youtube_get_comments(self.api_key, v_id, scrolls=3)
            n += len(c)
            temp = pd.DataFrame(c, columns=['comment'])
            new_comments = pd.concat([new_comments, temp], ignore_index=True)

        self.comments = pd.concat([new_comments, self.comments], ignore_index=True)

            
        ctx.send(f"added {n} comments from query")
```

where `Comments.youtube_search_keyword()` is defined as:

```
youtube = build("youtube", "v3", developerKey=config.youtube_api_key)
    search_keyword = youtube.search().list(q=query, part="id, snippet",
                                           maxResults=max_results).execute()

    results = search_keyword.get("items", [])

    titles = []
    ids = []
    channels = []
    for result in results:
        if result['id']['kind'] == "youtube#video":
            ids.append(result['id']['videoId'])
            titles.append(result["snippet"]["title"])
            channels.append(result["snippet"]["channelTitle"])


    return ids, titles, channels
```

and `Comments.youtube_get_comments()` is implemented similarly

Using `build` from `googleapiclient.discovery`

Comment: Please show us the source for `long_method_helper` - I suspect you're using a synchronous library like requests which will block the entire event loop.

Comment: you're missing an await

Comment: ok I added the contents of long_method_helper at the bottom @SuperStormer

Comment: wait where @FaridFakhry

Comment: in the short method but i suspect thats just the stackoverflow code you added

Comment: Oh yeah you're right but it's there in my actual code

Comment: Just because you made it async does not necessarily mean that it won't gobble up the loop. If you're running expensive non-async things, that can still end up blocking. Try replacing that method with `await asyncio.sleep(30)` and see if the error still persists.

Comment: @EricJin I made the replacement and it works how I want it to work (asynchronously), which is interesting. Is there a way that I can run expensive sync tasks separately? I saw a solution where they moved the task to another event loop running in another thread

Comment: @nikhilk Yeah, that's impossible, you'll have to run it in a separate thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so since the process I was trying to offload was a sync process, the way I solved this was by changing a few things:

```
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures
async def long_method(self, ctx, params):
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as pool:
        await ctx.send("long method started")
        
        # heavy processing
        result = await loop.run_in_executor(pool, self.long_method_helper, params)

        # light processes or other async calls
        await ctx.send("long method finished")
```

I also changed `long_method_helper` to be a sync function since that's essentially what it was before.

Answer (score 0):

discord.py comes with a loop, use this loop instead

```py
async def long_method(self, ctx, params):
    await ctx.send("starting long method")
    #instead of 
    #loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop = bot.loop #bot being your discord bot
    loop.create_task(self.long_method_helper(ctx, params))
```

Comment: I made the changes but it still has the same behavior as ```asyncio.get_event_loop()```